# How do motors without cooling fins cool down?

Tags: motor, induction, cooling

I understand that the fan on the motor shaft blows air through the motor fins thus cooling down the motor... However, motors without these cooling fins surely can't cool down the same way. I just don't understand how cooling is achieved in these kind of motors

Comment: Fins only increase the surface area. Without fins, you have a smaller surface area, so less surface cooling. But not none.

Answer (score 1):

They use radiative and convective heat transfer.

This relies on the surface area.